# Skype for buinsess online integration Chat Sysytem

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I am creating an app where Admin will login form his normally account and he/she can send and receive message to any skype user which is already connected to his/her skype.

for ex.
I will send an link to user to join me on skype. It can be through any way like whatsapp, fb or any other platform. Once user will join me I can send/receiver her/his message in my admin web portal which I have created.

Can any help me about it. I am using skype for buisness online and using ucwa but still stuck on authentication part of Azure AD.

If anyone has created this type of functionality plz let me know I want a demo or a docs which I can follow bcz Microsoft Docs sucks. It really sucks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/authenticationusingazuread

I passed all the steps for authentication but stuck on last step where I have to send resend auto discovery. Through this I will get the my app's end point and I will call the api using that end point.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{
 "_links":{
 "self":{"href":"https://webdirX.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/user"},
 "applications":{"href":"https://webpoolXY.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications"}
 }
}
```

I am following these steps but still unable to follow properly. If anyone has done it already please let me know.

Comment: I am not using any code for now. I am requesting all the request from browser. In the  last step where we resend the auto discovery request with bearer token I am getting 401 sometimes and sometimes 403 error. Because resend the home pool auto discovery directory will give me the user end point to use the rest api. That's why I am asking it

Comment: that would be very helpful but I think Skype for business has been deprecated now and Microsoft will no longer will provide APIs for new Skype for business Users.

Comment: So  now I moved to use Skype bot in my project but Skype bot also will no longer accepting new Bot registrations.